# facebook-js-sdk FB.api('/me', { fields: ['email'] }) not returning email when the user has signed up with phone number

Tags: javascript, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

****DISCLAMER:** I am aware there are similar question that has been solved by specifying the correct fields it needs which was a change made on v2.4. This is not the same problem or question.**

[facebook-js-sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/) Does not return a validated email address even though it meets the following criteria:

- It is set in the facebook account's settings under 'Personal details' > 'Contact Info'
- The scopes are set on user login (via `FB.login(callback, { scope: 'email' })`)
- The email field is specified on api request (`FB.api('/me?fields=email', callback)` or `FB.api('/me', { fields: ['email'] }, callback)`) according to [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)

I can confirm that the request being generated has `fields` query with `email` as value. (https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/me?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=%5B%22email%22%5D&method=get&pretty=0&sdk=joey&suppress_http_code=1 or https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/me?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=email&method=get&pretty=0&sdk=joey&suppress_http_code=1)
but the response comes back with just the id property, I.e. `{id: 00000000000000000}`.

If I delete the phone number from my facebook account, the above response will now include the `email` field.

If I later add a phone number again, from that point on the email field will persist.

So the behavior where the email field is not returned is only when:

- The user has registered an account initially with just their phone number
- The user has added an email after account registration

How would I correctly get the user's email address when set the first time after registering only with a phone number?